# Rotating a sprite on a canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a player class with a sprite and I want to make it face towards my mouse pointer.

I'm using this to work out what the rotation of the sprite should be:

```
this.rotation = -(Math.atan2(this.x - mouseState.x, this.y - mouseState.y) * 180 / Math.PI);
```

and then in my draw method of my `Player` class I'm doing this:

```
Player.prototype.draw = function() {
    window.ctx.save();
    window.ctx.translate(this.x + this.sprite.width / 2, this.y + this.sprite/height / 2);
    window.ctx.rotate(this.rotation);
    window.ctx.drawImage(this.sprite, this.x, this.y);
    window.ctx.restore();
}
```

it does something, however not what I want. The sprite seems to move wildly in a circle around the top left of the canvas (`x:0, y:0`).

How can I make the sprite face towards the mouse cursor, also using its centre point as the origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not translating back. Note the extra `window.ctx.translate` call I added below, and notice how I've add negative to both the x and y values.

```
Player.prototype.draw = function() {
    window.ctx.save();
    window.ctx.translate(this.x + this.sprite.width / 2, this.y + this.sprite/height / 2);
    window.ctx.rotate(this.rotation);
    window.ctx.translate(-this.x + this.sprite.width / 2, -this.y + this.sprite/height / 2);
    window.ctx.drawImage(this.sprite, this.x, this.y);
    window.ctx.restore();
}
```

Basically, what this is doing is moving (translating) the canvas context center to your object center, rotating (rotate), then you need to move the center point back from were you got it from.

Answer (score 0):

> Math.atan2(y,x)

Note that the `y` argument comes first, *then* the `x`. Switch your arguments around.

Also, it returns a value in radians, which you would know if you tried calling `Math.atan2(1,0)`. Remove the conversion to degrees.

> This is a clockwise rotation measured in radians

Meaning, again that you don't want your rad-deg conversion.

```
this.rotation = Math.atan2(this.y-mouseState.y, this.x-mouseState.x);

window.ctx.rotate(this.rotation);
```

Comment: The sprite isn't so wildly spinning thanks to not converting it to degrees, however it's still spinning in a large circle around the top left of the canvas.

Comment: You need to `rotate` first, *then* `translate`.